# How to use Lua with Redis?

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I am using Lua+nginx with OpenResty bundle. But problem comes when I try to connect Lua script with Redis, I'm not able to make successful connection. I have gone through a lot of links and blogs, But in the end it always fails. This is the snippet of code which I am trying.

```
   server {
       location /test {
           content_by_lua '
               local redis = require "resty.redis" // **Problem in code "Not able to require "resty.redis""**

               local red = redis:new()

               red:set_timeout(1000) -- 1 sec

               -- or connect to a unix domain socket file listened
               -- by a redis server:
               --     local ok, err = red:connect("unix:/path/to/redis.sock")

               local ok, err = red:connect("127.0.0.1", 6379)
               if not ok then
                   ngx.say("failed to connect: ", err)
                   return
               end
  }
}
```

Comment: is `/usr/local/openresty/lualib/resty/redis.lua` can be found?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "not able to require" means you are getting `module 'resty.redis' not found` message with a list of paths, the error indicates that you are missing the module. You need to check the paths that are listed and make sure that `resty/redis.lua` is in one of those folders. You will find that file in `lua-resty-redis-<version>` folder in your OpenResty installation.